# Coin toss where $Pr(H)=1/3$

Tags: probability

Question: A coin is tossed where the probability it lands on heads is $1/3$. What is the expected number of heads before tails?

My answer: number of heads before tails = $\frac{1}{3}^1+\frac{1}{3}^2+\frac{1}{3}^3+...$ $=$ $\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{3}} = \frac{3}{2}$

I don't know if this is right or not any input would be great, Thanks.

Comment: you should decrement it by 1, no?

Comment: Sorry, i misread your problem.  I thought you were asking for the number of trials you expect it to take before you see $T$, including the last throw.  If you don't count the actual throw of Tails, the answer should be one less.  Your computation is correct if you are counting the last throw.

Answer (score 4):

Let $X$ be a geometric random variable such that $X=k$ if and only if the first instance of tails is the $k$th flip.

With probability $p = \frac{2}{3}$ of getting tails on any given flip, this random variable has expectation

$$ E[X] = \frac{1}{p} = \frac{1}{\Big( \frac{2}{3} \Big)} = \frac{3}{2} = 1.5$$

In other words, we expect to get tails in $1.5$ flips. We then minus one flip to obtain the number of heads we expect to obtain before the instance of tails

$$ \frac{3}{2} - 1 = \frac{1}{2} $$

Hence, we expect to get heads $0.5$ times before we get tails.

Answer (score 3):

Almost there, it should be $3/2-1=0.5$. There is a chance you will get no heads before tails! So, you subtract 1 from your solution. There are two versions for the geometric distribution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution